# How to fetch data from php function from angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

I know how ajax works but I wanna know that how to retrieve data from a specific php function so I dont create a number of pages for each function 1 page can do all the work.

AngularJs:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller("usercontroller",function($scope,$http){
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "functions.php",
        data: {
            name: 'myname',
        },
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
       $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
    });
});
```

Php:

```
function abc(){
echo 'abc';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your PHP file. You should do something like this:

```
<?php

$post_date = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($post_date);

//now i am just printing the values
echo "Name : ".$data->name."n";
```

In PHP page we are going to retrieve the json data and decode using it json_decode. Remember, this is just example because you can improve your code. Im just giving you a minimalist way to do that.

Let me know if you need something else about it.

///////
NEW EDIT - Send variable to PHP
///////

**Angular**

```
$http({
        url: "urltopost.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            data: variable
        }
    }).success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$request = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
$variable = $request->data
```

Comment: sir but i want that data inside a function of php and retrive it by using angular ajax

Comment: from your php file, you just output variable like this: echo json_encode($result); and you will get your response :)

Comment: how can i send variables from angular to php

Comment: is there any solutions

Comment: You cannot use GET, you need use POST to get variables in PHP file ;)

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\Angularjs\front.php on line 183

Comment: whats the line 183 ? looks like you are trying get property that from non-object. Try to print_r($request) to see whats goin'On.

Comment: actually the thing is that that the post method is not sending variable to php its sending null

Comment: do you have any solution that how to send variables by post method

Comment: in your javascript code, fix your data to data: { 'message' : message }

Answer (score 0):

Add another key to `data` set to get specific output from specific function.
Just an idea to make it work, modify as desired

1. single File holding all the method/functions
2. single class manage all the ajax calls.
3. single json response call.

<kbd>**JS**</kbd>:

```
data: {
    name: 'myname',
    _method: 'my_custom_function',
},
```

and then in PHP check the request which function needs to be call for specific task.

using `$_REQUEST` is usefull wheather request is `POST` OR `GET` it is always cachable and then verify by `method_exists` if method exists in the class it will execute by `call_user_func` from the given class instance.

<kbd>**function.php**</kbd>

```
class Ajax_calls{
    // ... multiple functions goes here
    public function my_custom_function() {
      // Your logics
    }
}

if( isset( $_REQUEST ) ) {
    $obj    = new Ajax_calls();
    $method = $_REQUEST['_method'];
    if( method_exists($obj, $method) ) {
        $data = call_user_func(array($obj, $method));
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode("no function found");
    }
}
```

Comment: <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: _method in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\series\Angularjs\category.php</b> on line <b>81</b><br /> "no function found"

Comment: you are not passing the `_method` in your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add code to your php file with the functions to choose the function to execute? Checking the value of the variable you are sending to functions.php and then making the decision. For example:

```
$action = $_GET["name"];
switch ($action){
    case "myname":
        abc();
        break;
    default:
        echo "";
        break;
}

function abc(){
    echo "abc";
}
```

I prefer separate the logic of the "controller" and the functions file having a controller.php

```
require_once('functions.php');
$action = $_GET["name"];
switch ($action){
    case "myname":
        abc();
        break;
    default:
        echo "";
        break;
}
```

and a functions.php

```
function abc(){
    echo "abc";
}
```

But that's up to you

Answer (score -2):

You could do it by passing the function name as GET-variable. and then use `eval ()`

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller("usercontroller",function($scope,$http){
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        data: "fx=abc",
        dataType: "text",
        url : "functions.php",
        data: {
            name: 'myname',
        },
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
    });
});
```

```php
if (function_exists ($_GET['fx']))
    eval ($_GET['fx'].'();');

function abc(){
    echo 'abc';
}
```

Comment: Yeah then someone just passes `echo exec('ls -lr'); function test(){} test` as `$_GET['fx']` SOUNDS FUN

Comment: @IsThisJavascript. of course but sanitizing user input is a no-brainer. i will edit my post.

Comment: I wouldn't use `eval`, I'd just use the parameter to figure out what function to call: `if ('foo' == $functionName) { foo(); }` Slightly safer, but overall we're probably leading this person down the wrong path. You should create as many Php pages as make sense. Don't cram it all into one page.

Comment: you need take care about variables. Please, check your code again because im pretty sure you'll understood that mistakes you did about data.